# How does add(index, element) method work behind the scenes using LinkedList?

Tags: java, doubly-linked-list

When adding an element at a certain index using the **add(index, element)** method in an *ArrayList*, it places the element at that index, while all the other elements change their indexes by 1 (they move in memory). That's why an *ArrayList* has the complexity O(n) when adding an element at a certain position.

In case of a doubly *LinkedList*, I know that the elements have pointers to the previous element and also for the next one.

My question is, when using the **add(index, element)** method related to a *LinkedList*, what will actually happen behind the scenes? I know that using the *LinkedList* the rest of the elements don't move in memory, so how come they can still be placed at a certain index without moving in memory?

Comment: The indices on a LinkedList don't correspond to contiguous memory locations.  Instead, the `get()` method requires a list traversal to access the correct index.  This is why `ArrayList::get` has a complexity of O(1) (it can just jump to the correct memory address), but `LinkedList::get` has a complexity of O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a new element to a linked list at a specified index requires walking down the list (from either the head or tail), and then *splicing* in the new element.  The [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java) for `LinkedList#add(int index, E element)` reveals as much:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    checkPositionIndex(index);

    if (index == size)
        linkLast(element);
    else
        linkBefore(element, node(index));
}
```

Should the index be pointing to the final item in the list, it simply appends a new node to the end.  Otherwise, it calls `linkBefore()`, which does a bit of splicing work (I won't bother to include its source code as well).

Note here that adding a new node to a linked list does not necessarily involve moving anything in the already existing list.  Rather, it mostly involves moving around references in the background.

Comment: @Michael I actually was worried someone would call me out on that.  I changed my language a bit.

Comment: Welcome to pedant country

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `add(index, element)` looks like this:

```
public void add(int index, E element) {
    checkPositionIndex(index);

    if (index == size)
        linkLast(element);
    else
        linkBefore(element, node(index));
}
```

If you're adding an element to the tail of the `LinkedList`, the `linkLast` method can be executed in constant time; the `LinkedList` always has direct access to its last element, and no traversing is required.

Otherwise, the `node` method is what's expensive, as a traversal through at most half of the list is required:

```
Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

The elements aren't required to *move in memory* because they each refer to their previous and next nodes in the `LinkedList`, as you can see below in `linkBefore`:

```
void linkBefore(E e, Node<E> succ) {
    // assert succ != null;
    final Node<E> pred = succ.prev;
    final Node<E> newNode = new Node<>(pred, e, succ);
    succ.prev = newNode;
    if (pred == null)
        first = newNode;
    else
        pred.next = newNode;
    size++;
    modCount++;
}
```